# Mongoose not deleting subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My delete route is

```
const id = req.body.id;
const postId = req.body.postId;

if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    Comment.findByIdAndRemove({ _id: id }, (err, cRes) => {
        if (err) return err;

        Post.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: postId }, {
            $pull: {
                Comments: {
                    _id: id
                }
            }
        }, (err, doc, res) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
        });
    });
}
```

And the problem is that it does delete the comment from the `Comment` table but it doesn't delete the comment to the related `Post`, why is that?

**PostSchema**

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 Author: String,
 Title: String,
 Description: String,
 Comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'   
 }],
 Tags: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, ref: 'Tag'
 }],
 CreatedOn: Date,
 LastEditOn: Date
});
```

**CommentSchema**

```
var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 _postId: {
    type: String,
    ref: 'Post' 
 },
 Author: String,
 Description: String,
 CreatedOn: Date,
 LastEditBy: Date
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to put `_id` during `pull` because you haven't mentioned any key in `Comments` of `Post` collection.

```
if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    Comment.findByIdAndRemove({ _id: id }, (err, cRes) => {
        if (err) return err;

        Post.update({ _id: postId }, {
            $pull: {
                Comments: id
            }
        }, (err, doc, res) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
        });
    });
}
```

If you define `_id` in post schema like

```
Comments: [{
    _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }
 }]
```

then your query could have worked.

Comment: That solved the problem, but isn't `ref` exactly telling the `Post` comments to keep the `ObjectId` of the `CommentSchema`?

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. Thanks